# htaccess to redirect to Facebook Page temporally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanna temporally redirect my domain to my facebook page till we have our website ready.

How can i do that? I checked for examples and it provides me a 301 redirect.
Should i be doing a 301 redirect?

**Edit:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch 302 ^ https://www.facebook.com/NomadHQ
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `301` for a temporary redirect otherwise your SEO ranking will be messed up later. Use `302` instead like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^ http://facebook.com/mypage
```

Comment: yeah :D it does. whats the main diff between 301/302?

Comment: 301 is permanent redirect and search engines as well as browsers will aggressively cache those redirects. 302 is called temporary redirect.

Comment: better answer than chatgpt